# What is a consumer in Java?

Tags: java

Every time I've seen a consumer being used, it's used alongside generics. Despite this, I can't really find any good resources to properly explain when and where I should be using consumers. Does anyone have any information about consumers?

Thanks

Comment: Google "consumer producer pattern" and you should find many resources.

Comment: Are you talking about an interface Consumer?

Answer (score 6):

Despite various info you can find about "Producer/Consumer" pattern, in Java there is a specific functional interface called `Consumer`, which belongs to the package `java.util.function`. That is just one of the various functional interfaces (there are 4 main ones: `Consumer`, `Function`, `Predicate` and `Supplier`, along with  additional subinterfaces) which Java makes available to be used in particular for defining lambda expressions, to be used in combination with Java Stream.
If you look at the specification, [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html), this functional interface is defined over a specific target type `T` and exposes a method called `accept`, whose signature is the following:

```
void accept(T t);
```

So, the `Consumer` functional interface is particularly useful when you want to define a function that performs some actions over an instance of type `T` and doesn't return any value.
The most typical usage is when you want to scroll all elements of a `java.util.Iterable` object and you want to perform an action over each element, and this is possible by just passing a lambda expression to the default method `forEach` exposed by the interface.

Here is an example:

```
List<String> myList = List.of("Element1", "Element2", "Element3");
myList.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

As you can see, the above code just creates an immutable `List` of `String` elements, and the method `forEach` just perform the action specified by the `Consumer` in input (which is the lambda expression `s -> System.out.println(s)`), which simply prints each element of the list in the standard output.
Of course there are infinite possibilities, but my intentions is just to give you an idea of what a `Consumer` is in Java.